# WPF - Access parent properties from internal control's part ControlTemplate trigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, controltemplate

**Short question:**

In case you have a control consisting of multiple parts (like DatePicker, which consists of PART_Root, PART_Button, PART_Textbox etc...), how can you bind a trigger of an inner part's control template to validity of the entire control?

**Long question:**

I am trying to customize the DatePicker control template, and it consists of several major parts, most importantly:

- PART_Root
- PART_Button
- PART_TextBox

I am overriding the template of PART_TextBox by targeting DatePickerTextBox with a style, which in essence replaces only the PART_TextBox content of DatePicker.

Now, I want to implement some special custom validation elements in the control template of PART_Textbox, but I am unable to trigger them to show. I have tried using

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Validation.HasError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}">
```

but for some reason it does not work...

Comment: Funny thing, the binding works fine when set directly on Visibility property of elements that are being shown by the upper DateTrigger :S

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that the object that you are binding implements the interface INotifyDataErrorInfo. For an example on the implementation see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)